# How to handle unsupported column in custom content provider

Tags: android

I have a custom content provider for sharing files. For columns (via query method) i support only `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` and `OpenableColumns.SIZE`.

While testing i noticed that Photos app (Google+) have problems (NullPointerException) opening images through my content provider, because they are retrieving _data column, which is not supported in my content provider, and for it i return null (for column names and values).

Later i updated this part of code, so now it returns in columns array _data column, but it's value as null.

It seems that this works now ok in Photos app, but i'm curious... Does anybody know if this is in general specified/standardized, what we should return in case of unsupported column?

Part of confusion is: should we on side of content provider handle such scenarios as i did, or should apps that uses content providers do additional checking? Since some apps can check if column exists, then do something with value (but value will be null). On other side, other apps can expect column, and assume if column exists, then value should also exists.

I know that the best approach is to cover all situations, but initial question remains: is such handling specified somewhere in the documentation?

Here is also section of code for better imagination:

```
String cols[] = new String[projection.length];
Object vals[] = new Object[projection.length];

for(int i=0; i<projection.length; i++){
    //projection is passed to query() by 3rd party app
    String column = projection[i];

    if ( OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME.equals(column) ) {
        cols[i] = OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME;
        vals[i] = name;
    }else if ( OpenableColumns.SIZE.equals(column) ) {
        cols[i] = OpenableColumns.SIZE;
        vals[i] = file.length();
    }else{
        //THIS PART OF CODE WAS LATER ADDED
            //for unsupported column return column name
            //but it's value will be null
        cols[i] = column;
        vals[i] = null;
    }
}

MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(cols, 1);
mc.addRow(vals);
```

Comment: what does Photos app. have to do with your provider ?

Comment: Photo app is using my content provider (ACTION_VIEW with content uri). Photo app is only example where i noticed problems, i'm asking in general.

Comment: is your CP small enough to post it here ?

Comment: Too big. Simplified question: should i return in case of unsupported _data column cols[1]=null; vals[1]=null; or should i return cols[1]="_data"; vals[i]=null;

Comment: imho the question is why your CP is called by unknown client ?

Comment: My app have content provider through which i share some private files with other apps. In case of sharing, user decide with which app open certain file. So i pass then to this app VIEW intent with uri (which is pointing to my content provider). This is standard way how to share data to 3rd party apps... Ps: content provider is exported as public in manifest file.

Comment: ok, i see, i think that it should be handled by a client app: you cannot do everything in your CP to make a client happy

Comment: i agree with that. but i would like to satisfy as many as possible of 3rd party apps :) and if there is specified way how to handle such scenarios, i would like to use it...

Comment: but it looks like that it isn't specified and we should always in client app check first if column exists and then check also if value is not null.

Comment: ok, i found that if you are exposing media files in your CP then its query method should return MediaStore.MediaColumns