# Android ContentProvider Cursor issue

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to write a content provider for my application that allows access to some files that my app stores on the SD Card. The files' names are hashes of their content URI, so for example `content://my.app.files/test.pdf` would sit at `/sdcard/data/Android/my.app/cache/MD5(my.app.files/test.pdf)` where `MD5()` is the MD5 hash.

My content provider looks like this:

```
public class CacheContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String[] COLUMNS= { OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE };
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://my.app.files/");
    private DiskCache mCache;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        PotDroidApplication.initImageLoader(getContext());
        final ImageLoader il = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mCache = il.getDiskCache();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        final File file = getFileForUri(uri);

        final int lastDot = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
        if (lastDot >= 0) {
            final String extension = file.getName().substring(lastDot + 1);
            final String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            if (mime != null) {
                return mime;
            }
        }

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final File f = getFileForUri(getContentUriFromUrlOrUri(uri.toString()));

        if (f.exists()) {
            return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        }

        throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());
    }

    private File getFileForUri(Uri uri) {
        return DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(uri.toString(), mCache);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        final File file = getFileForUri(uri);

        if (projection == null) {
            projection = COLUMNS;
        }

        String[] cols = new String[projection.length];
        Object[] values = new Object[projection.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String col : projection) {
            if (OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME.equals(col)) {
                cols[i] = OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME;
                values[i++] = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            } else if (OpenableColumns.SIZE.equals(col)) {
                cols[i] = OpenableColumns.SIZE;
                values[i++] = file.length();
            }
        }
        cols = copyOf(cols, i);
        values = copyOf(values, i);
        final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(cols, 1);
        cursor.addRow(values);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
    }

    public static Uri getContentUriFromUrlOrUri(String rawUrl) {
        if(rawUrl.startsWith(CONTENT_URI.toString()))
            return Uri.parse(rawUrl);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(rawUrl.replace("%20","+"));
            return Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + url.getHost() + url.getPath());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String[] copyOf(String[] original, int newLength) {
        final String[] result = new String[newLength];
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, result, 0, newLength);
        return result;
    }

    private static Object[] copyOf(Object[] original, int newLength) {
        final Object[] result = new Object[newLength];
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, result, 0, newLength);
        return result;
    }

    public static class HashFileNameGenerator extends Md5FileNameGenerator {
        @Override
        public String generate(String url) {
            Uri uri = getContentUriFromUrlOrUri(url);
            if(uri == null)
                return super.generate(url);
            return super.generate(uri.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

The Provider seems to work fine resolving the `content://` URIs and sharing with certain apps, e.g., Dropbox, works fine as well. However, some Apps throw Exceptions when I try to share my files with them, for example the Acrobat PDF converter. The exception is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
...
```

So, apparently, the app is looking for some column that is not present in the Cursor I return via the `query()` method. What am I doing wrong? I basically copied the `query()` method from Android's native `FileProvider`.

Comment: override MatrixCursor.getColumnIndex and see what columns does it want

Comment: I should have thought of that. :) Thank you, will try it out tonight.

Comment: or/and getColumnIndexOrThrow

Comment: Both methods are not called, for whatever reason. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: not called? unmöglich, how can it read your cursor then, not knowing what column index to use

Comment: Well, complains about some `CursorWindow` misfunction, who knows what cursor that one wraps and what happened internally.

Comment: sure, you are right, the stack trace is not about MatrixCursor as it doesent extend AbstractWindowedCursor

Comment: and what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502398/how-to-handle-unsupported-column-in-custom-content-provider "if you are exposing media files in your CP then its query method should return MediaStore.MediaColumns ", check it out...

Comment: That was it! I needed to implement the `MediaStore.MediaColumns` in the cursor. Please repost your answer as an actual answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you have to return all of them?

Comment: I am not sure, I returned all and it worked. I won't not try out, which ones are actually needed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are exposing media files in your ContentProvider then its `query()` method should return MediaStore.MediaColumns